# SSMS 18.0 switching between tabs problem

Tags: ssms

Does anybody have the same problem with new SSMS 18.0?

I have opened more tabs with some code inside. When switching between tabs the window (code inside the window) is rendered slow and the code is mostly overlaped with a code from previous tab. See image for example:

[image]

I wonder whether it's just mine or general bug? Where would you recommend me to report this?

**UPDATE**

You can vote for this to be repaired at Azure Feedback site here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37474042-ssms-18-0-redraw-issues-when-switching-between-mul

Comment: Looks like a Windows/graphics card issue. Not repainting the screen properly

Comment: But it comes only with SSMS 18.0. No previous versions or other apps appears to have such behavior.

Comment: Yep ive seen the same on win10 on a hp elitebook. It wasnt doing that with 17.9.

Comment: I'm also on Win10, Fujitsu Lifebook U745. SSMS 17.9 is completely fine.

Comment: I have the same issue but the 18 version has no similar issue.

Comment: Question should be opened to allow users to explain how changing graphics settings may help resolve issue in 18.X. Even if some users are having issues it is not off-topic if they wish to use the site to find answers for the MS provided tool that a DBA would use.